Django password reset with front end UI
I'm working on a project that uses Django as the backend and next.js/react.js on the front end.  The issue I'm running into is trying to reset the password using the UI of my front end.  All of the solutions I've found involve creating the UI on the backend server with templates which I would prefer not to do.
I'm able to get the following email from Django(dj_rest_auth) that provides a link with the server domain.
Hello from MyApp!

You're receiving this email because you or someone else has requested a password reset for your user account.
It can be safely ignored if you did not request a password reset. Click the link below to reset your password.

http://localhost:8000/password-reset-confirm/k/cd01t1-dfsdfdfwer2/

I've tried to override the PasswordResetSerializer like so but it doesn't work.
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer

class MyPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):

    def get_email_options(self) :
      
        return {
            'email_template_name': 'http://localhost:3000/new-password'
        }

urls.py
    path('password-reset/', PasswordResetView.as_view()),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),  

And in my settings.py file I have
...
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'myapp.serializers.MyPasswordResetSerializer'
}
...

How can I change the link in the reset password email to one that sends the user to the client to create their new password?

If you're using dj-rest-auth, why do those password reset functions not fit the need? After all, that library was made specifically for the scenario you are describing.

That was my thought process as well. In this specific situation, it doesn’t seem like you can send the user to a different front end server to enter in their new password.

It must be implemented through a Django template.
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordResetForm
from dj_rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from django.conf import settings

class MyPasswordResetSerializer(PasswordResetSerializer):
    password_reset_form_class = PasswordResetForm

    def get_email_options(self):
        return {
            "subject_template_name": "email/password_reset_subject.txt",
            "email_template_name": "email/password_reset_message.html",
            "html_email_template_name": "email/password_reset_message.html",
            "extra_email_context": {
                "settings": settings,
            }
        }

The above paths are connected through the Django Template.
In the environment I tested, I implemented it in the authenticate app, so it connects to the authenticate/template/email/password_reset_message.html file.
password_reset_subject.txt
password change

password_reset_message.html
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>

This is the result of testing through the above template.



The only solution I've found thus far is to use a third-party library called Djoser.  Here are the settings it took to get everything working.
settings.py
DOMAIN = 'localhost:3000'
SITE_NAME = 'localhost'

DJOSER = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'username/reset/{uid}/{token}',
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SERIALIZERS': {},
}

urls.py
urlpatterns = [
  ...
  path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
  ...
]

Now, I send the user's email to http://localhost:8000/auth/users/reset_password/ and the user receives the following email.

You're receiving this email because you requested a password reset for
your user account at localhost.
Please go to the following page and choose a new password:
http://localhost:3000/password/reset/UWA/cd0m9t-dfwwe323g

From there, you can get the params from the URL like normal on the client and send the new password to the /users/reset_password_confirm/ endpoint.
Here is a link for more information on their endpoints.
